# I hit an area of my elbow and had a burning sensation throughout my hand

Tags: human-biology, injury

I happened to bump the side of my right-hand elbow on a corner and suddenly felt a burning sensation on the right side of the hand elbow-up. Any theories that could describe what I recite?

Comment: While this sounds like you hit your [ulnar nerve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulnar_nerve), it also sounds like a question about personal medical health which are generally considered off-topic on this site.

Comment: Ulnar nerve supplies sensory innervation to medial 1.5/5 of the hand(i e. Medial 1.5 digits). So when you hit your elbow, ulnar nerve is involved (it runs over medial epicondyle of humerus). So there is a kind of burning sensation felt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's often referred to as hitting your funny bone:

Heres one reference on the subject:
https://www.huffpost.com/entry/hitting-your-funny-bone-i_b_12201698

and here is another:
[https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/21474/what-funny-bone-and-why-does-hitting-it-hurt-so-much#:~:text=When%20you%20hit%20your%20funny,the%20ring%20and%20pinky%20fingers](https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/21474/what-funny-bone-and-why-does-hitting-it-hurt-so-much#:%7E:text=When%20you%20hit%20your%20funny,the%20ring%20and%20pinky%20fingers).

The ulnar nerve is exposed near the bones of the elbow, especially if the elbow is bent. You can probably locate it with your index. If you hit the ulnar nerve near the elbow, it can be felt in the little finger and one side of the hand.